# Couple Questions Regarding the Adapter

Tags: java, android, arraylist

```
public class AdapterQuestion extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterQuestion.ViewQuestion>{
private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
//this is an arrayList of questionData objects
private ArrayList<QuestionData> data =new ArrayList<>();
//Created the layoutInflator
public AdapterQuestion(Context context){
    //get from context
    mLayoutInflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);

}
public void setBloglist(ArrayList<QuestionData> data){
    this.data =data;
    notifyItemRangeChanged(0, data.size());
    System.out.print("Size of the array "+data.size());
}
@Override
public ViewQuestion onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    //inflates the customQuestion view or converts it to java code
    View view= mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.customquestion, null);
    //We now want to convert the View into a ViewQuestion, view Question takes
    //a view so we pass the view into view question and then return it.

    ViewQuestion holder=new ViewQuestion(view);
    return holder;
}
//ViewGroup parent and ViewType are not being assigned.
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewQuestion holder, int position) {
    //here we need to bind the data to our view, there is currently no Data!
    //We need to get the data from our JSON
    //Parameters is a ViewHolder and a Position
    QuestionData currentBlog= data.get(position);
    holder.answerText.setText(currentBlog.getMtext());
    holder.answerId.setText(currentBlog.getId());
    holder.mVotes.setText(currentBlog.getVotes());
    holder.mLikeButton.setTag(currentBlog);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public class ViewQuestion extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    //once we create it once the reclycer view will automatically recycle it
    private TextView answerText;
    private TextView answerId;
    private TextView mVotes;
    private LikeButton mLikeButton;

    public ViewQuestion (View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        //here we are finding the views by their ID
        answerText=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.answerText);
        answerId=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.answerId);
        mVotes=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.VoteTextView);
        mLikeButton=(LikeButton)itemView.findViewById(R.id.heart_buttons);

        mLikeButton.setOnLikeListener(new OnLikeListener() {
            @Override
            public void liked(LikeButton likeButton) {
                Voting vote = new Voting();
                vote.onUpVote(convertToString(),getAdapterPosition(),ViewQuestion.this);
                  System.out.print("Adapter      Position"+getAdapterPosition());
            }
            @Override
            public void unLiked(LikeButton likeButton) {
                Voting onDown=new Voting();
                onDown.onDownVote(convertToString(), getAdapterPosition(), ViewQuestion.this);

            }
        });

    }
    public String getVoteView(){
        String voteView=mVotes.getText().toString();
        return voteView;
    }
    public String convertToString(){
        String converted=answerId.getText().toString();
        return converted;
    }
    public int convertToInt(){
        String converted=answerId.getText().toString();
        int ConvertedInt=Integer.parseInt(converted);
        return ConvertedInt;
    }
}
}
```

1.First off, why do we extend  RecyclerView.Adapter as an arrayList? 
2.`public void setBloglist(ArrayList<QuestionData> data){
        this.data =data;
        notifyItemRangeChanged(0, data.size());
        System.out.print("Size of the array "+data.size());
    }` 
In the method above, we passed in an ArrayList, and we set the data of the Arraylist to the data passed in but dont we have to set the data in the ViewHolder? 
3. `super(itemView); Why does the ViewHolder extend super? isnt that itself?`

Answer (score 0):

1. It is not ArrayList it is generics
2. this keyword refers to the current object so we are setting the value of the data
   instance variable in the `AdapterQuestion`'s object to the value passed as method arguement
3. the ViewHolder does'nt extend a class named super but your `ViewQuestion` class extends `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` class ,the `super(itemView);`is used to call the `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` constructor

Comment: Oh its using the Recycler.viewholders constructor?

Comment: yes it is using the constructor ..[generics in java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html)